# Calculating matrix derivatives with MATLAB or MATHEMATICA?

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I'd like to calculate the following derivative,

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\|(f(C)\cdot f(C)^{+}-I)\cdot u\|^2)}{dC}
\end{equation}

Where $C$ is a matrix of dimension $n\times k$ (s.t $k < n$).
And $f$ is a differentiable function of $C$. Do you have suggestions on how to solve this problem using MATH tools or a cookbook?

Answer (score 2):

Write the function in terms of the Frobenius product (:) and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
L &= (ff^+-I)U:(ff^+-I)U \cr\cr
dL &= 2\,(ff^+-I)U:d(ff^+)U \cr
   &= 2\,(ff^+-I)UU^T:(df\,f^+ + f\,df^+) \cr
   &\equiv W:(df\,f^+ + f\,df^+) \cr
   &= Wf^{+T}:df \,+\, f^TW:df^+ \cr
}$$ 
Now the trick is to know that $f^T(ff^+-I)=0$ and therefore $f^TW=0$.

This reduces the differential to
$$\eqalign{
dL &= Wf^{+T}:df \cr
}$$ 
Since $dL = (\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}):df$ the derivative must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} &= Wf^{+T} \cr
 &= 2\,(ff^+-I)UU^T f^{+T}
}$$ 
To get the derivative with respect to $C$ I will make a few assumptions, since you didn't tell us anything about the function $f(C)$.

Since the shape of $C$ is not square, I assume that you are applying a scalar function element-wise to the matrix components. And that you know the derivative of the function in the scalar case, i.e. $f'(x)= \frac{df(x)}{dx}\,\,\,$

When applied element-wise to a matrix argument ($C$), the differential of a function can be expressed using the Hadamard product ($\circ$) as
$$\eqalign{
df &= f' \circ dC \cr
}$$ 
The differential of $L$ can be written as
$$\eqalign{
dL &= \Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}\Big):df \cr
  &= \Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}\Big):(f' \circ dC) \cr
  &= \Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}\circ f'\Big): dC \cr
}$$ 
That means the derivative of $L$ with respect to $C$ is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial L}{\partial C} &= \Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}\Big)\circ f' \cr
}$$ 
If you are uncomfortable with the Frobenius product, you can replace it with the trace function, since $\,\,A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$.